# FindNextFile ERROR_INVALID_NAME

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to use the WINAPI functions **FindFirstFile** and **FindNextFile**.
However, I'm experiencing some issues.

When I first call the function FindFirstFile it works fine. I've got a valid handler and the first folder/file name is properly populated inside the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure. No error is found with GetLastError.

Then, I call FindNextFile which returns true as there are more folders in the directory I'm scanning. But I can't retrieve the next folder/file name and  GetLastError returns 123 (0x7B) ERROR_INVALID_NAME.
I'm a little confused as it says in the official documentation that if an error occurs it should return 0.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero and the lpFindFileData parameter contains information about the next file or directory found.
> **If the function fails, the return value is zero and the contents of lpFindFileData are indeterminate. To get extended error information, call the GetLastError function.**
> If the function fails because no more matching files can be found, the GetLastError function returns ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES.

I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 x64.
Here is a sample code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public uint dwFileAttributes;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    public uint dwReserved0;
    public uint dwReserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string cAlternateFileName;
}
```

...

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindFirstFile", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindFirstFile", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile, ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindClose", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);
```

...

```
public static void Test()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA metaDataFile = new WIN32_FIND_DATA();

    IntPtr nextHandle = FileScanner.FindFirstFile("C:\\*", ref metaDataFile);
    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); // This equals 0x0 ERROR_SUCCESS
    Console.WriteLine(metaDataFile.cFileName); // This equals $Recycle.Bin

    /* Check invalid handler */
    if (nextHandle != new IntPtr(-1L))
    {
        bool moreFiles = true;
        while (moreFiles)
        {
            moreFiles = FileScanner.FindNextFile(nextHandle, ref metaDataFile);
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); // This equals 0x7B ERROR_INVALID_NAME
            Console.WriteLine(metaDataFile.cFileName); // This equals $Recycle.Bin and this value never change. 
        }
    
    FindClose(nextHandle);
    }
}
```

For some reason, moreFiles is always true and GetLastError returns ERROR_INVALID_NAME ...

If you need any details please ask me.
Any help would really be appreciated !

Comment: Don't call `GetLastError()` unless something actually fails (i.e. returns a documented failure code), otherwise the results are meaningless.

Comment: When reinventing the wheel, make sure that what you have come up with actually does resemble a wheel. If that is too tedious, go with [System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx) or [System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) instead. Complete functionality is documented at [System.IO.Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Directory.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` is the API call reports failure. In the case of `FindNextFile` it does so by returning `false`. You are checking the value returned by `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` indiscriminately.

The documentation makes this clear when it tells you how the functions indicate failure. You even linked the text. But you said:

> I'm a little confused as it says in the official documentation that if an error occurs it should return 0.

That's right. So check the return value against `0`. In the case of a `BOOL` marshalled as C# `bool`, that means that the function returns `false` if it fails. But you simply ignored the return value and tested the value returned by `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`, something altogether different.

The code should be more like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd = new WIN32_FIND_DATA();

    IntPtr findHandle = FileScanner.FindFirstFile("C:\\*", ref fd);
    if (findHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw new Win32Exception();

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fd.cFileName);
    } while (FileScanner.FindNextFile(findHandle, ref fd));

    // you might check that Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
    // at this point, otherwise the enumeration failed abnormally

    if (!FindClose(findHandle))
        throw new Win32Exception();
}
```

Your other problem, and it's what hurting you most, is your p/invoke declarations. Look closely at this one:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindFirstFile", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile,
    ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
```

The `EntryPoint` is not correct. So you are actually calling `FindFirstFile` instead of `FindNextFile` and it's hardly surprising that fails.

Specifying the `EntryPoint` when you don't need to is simply asking for trouble. And you've fallen right into the trap. I'd declare these imports like so:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName,
    ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile,
    ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);
```

Note that there's no need for the `return` attribute since `UnmanagedType.Bool` is the default.

And then you'd need to change the `CharSet` on the struct to be `CharSet.Unicode` to match. There's no point at all in opting for ANSI here.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    ....
}
```

Finally, all of this code seems to me to be pointless. What's wrong with `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`?

Comment: 1) This may be a matter of opinion, and you're free to disagree, but when I define a p/Invoke signature I usually make it explicit which version of the function I want to call (ie- `FindFirstFileW` instead of `FindFirstFile`).  2) [`CA1414`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182206.aspx) specifies that you should give use the `MarshalAs` attribute for boolean returns.  3) You may want to lead with the last paragraph, since this is a completely academic exercise. 4) All that said, `+1` for a well written answer.

Comment: @theB All valid points. Thank you. I'll let the asker read your comments rather than yet another edit, on my phone!!

Comment: Thank you for all your good advice and detailed answer ! That's true I shouldn't have specified the entry points ...
I wish I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. 

I'd used GetFiles as well as the methods you mentioned above before. I was looking for an async equivalent but I couldn't find any. So that's why I've ended up with this solution which to be honest I don't like either.

Comment: However, I don't understand when you say "But you simply ignored the return value and tested the value returned by Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(). "
Sorry I had a tough night maybe I'm missing something but to me I do test the value returned by FindNextFile. Otherwise sorry if I'm wrong (shame on me ^^)
Btw, I was calling GetLastWin32Error in this way to test the behaviour of the whole. 
Now that it works I can rewrite that with proper error handling.

Comment: You do test the value returned, but only after calling GetLastWin32Error. If FindNextFile succeeds, the last error has no meaning. You make the same mistake with FindFirstFile. We see this classic mistake >10 times a day here btw.